# Goal was rejected by server using Rviz and Nav2 in ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2, rviz, ros-humble, plugin, nav2

I am trying to follow the [spatio_temporal_voxel_layer](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer) on [(STVL) Using an External Costmap Plugin](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_stvl.html) tutorial on Navigation2.
I use the latest package version [2.2.0](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer/releases/tag/2.2.0), but it say `Release for Galactic` so I hope is the correct one.

Now I can compile it without problem, but when I try to use it in the [navigation2_with_stvl] (https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_stvl.html) tutorial, I get the following output after setting the initial position and give it the first waypoint with RViz(I have modify the [nav2_params.yaml](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_bringup/params/nav2_params.yaml) as the tutorial explain):

```
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1700845699.314181660] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845699.348767387] [rviz2]: Setting estimate pose: Frame:map, Position(-1.99375, -0.559368, 0), Orientation(0, 0, -1.83399e-06, 1) = Angle: -3.66798e-06
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845699.349127280] [amcl]: initialPoseReceived
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1700845699.349206579] [amcl]: Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1700845699.348702 but the latest data is at time 128.072000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [base_footprint])
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845699.349239411] [amcl]: Setting pose (128.061000): -1.994 -0.559 -0.000
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845699.401963891] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 126.147 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845699.593500969] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 126.347 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845699.613405946] [amcl]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.347 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845699.613462013] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame' at time 128.200 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845699.813652402] [amcl]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.547 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845699.813708024] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame' at time 128.400 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845699.817287513] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 126.546 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845700.009884203] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 126.746 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845700.015340347] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame' at time 128.600 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845700.202011588] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 126.946 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845700.216485181] [amcl]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.947 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845700.216541133] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame' at time 128.801 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845700.394145195] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.146 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845700.416860933] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame' at time 129.000 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845708.610880344] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.347 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845708.815429917] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.547 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845709.020468183] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.747 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845709.224721206] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 127.947 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845709.427977416] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 128.147 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845709.632029863] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 128.347 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845709.836569659] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 128.547 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845710.008188189] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 128.747 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845710.213399003] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 128.947 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-5] Start navigation
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1700845710.788743929] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigator's default behavior tree.
[rviz2-5] [ERROR] [1700845710.789156195] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: Goal was rejected by server
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1700845715.092527000] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dro
```

I understand that the problem is related to the navigation pose sended by RViz, but I do not know how to fix it...
Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! By seeing the time-related errors, I suspect some of your nodes are using different clocks. Can you please synchronize the clock to confirm the same time across all machines?

Comment: The simulation is running on the same machine, do you mean I have to use "use_sim_time=True" ?